# Windows Command Line Join WAV files

Tags: wav

Looking to join wav files together with a Win command line.
I need to take different time/sample start/end sections out of a wav file and join them into a new file.
Was looking at SoX but was not sure if it could do this, it's good as it will do pitch and tempo if need be.
I will have a script that will pick the many section needed from the source wav file/s and write to a table then send this to the command line.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: This tool might work for you - it was designed specifically for command line WAV splicing: https://github.com/sobitcorp/FlacMyGame/blob/main/wavedit.exe

Answer (score 0):

For example, a long song begins with two verses which start (as determined e.g. by using the play
command with the trim (start) effect) at times 0:30.125 and 1:03.432. The following commands

```
sox too-long.wav part1.wav trim 0 30.130
(5 ms excess, after the first verse starts)
sox too-long.wav part2.wav trim 1:03.422
(5 ms excess plus 5 ms leeway, before the second verse starts)
sox part1.wav part2.wav just-right.wav splice 30.130
```

trim {position(+)}
Cuts portions out of the audio. Any number of positions may be given; audio is not sent to the
output until the first position is reached. The effect then alternates between copying and discarding
audio at each position. Using a value of 0 for the first position parameter allows copying from
the beginning of the audio.
For example,

```
sox infile outfile trim 0 10 (start sec length secs)
```

will copy the first ten seconds

```
sox short.wav long.wav longer.wav
```

concatenates two audio files.